# rosjava and Android dependencies

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and android, but I would like to use rosjava to drive my robots. Can rosjava work on non-android OSes, such as Debian? Or, must my robot be deployed with android?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10677/rosjava-and-android-dependencies/) by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjava is a pure Java implementation of ROS. It can run anywhere you have a VM that supports Java.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on 2011-07-26**:
Great - thank you for the clarification!

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-07-25**:
You don't need the Android SDK to build rosjava. You only need it if you intend to build an Android app.

**Comment by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on 2011-07-25**:
Ok thanks for that info! So, as I understand it, the Android SDK is only for building the rosjava. Is that correct?